# Weighted rowmeans in R

Tags: r, weighted

I am trying to created a weighted average for each week, across multiple columns. My data looks like this:

```
week <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
col_a <- c(1,2,2,4,2,7)
col_b <- c(4,2,3,1,2,5)
col_c <- c(4,2,3,2,2,4)
dfreprex <- data.frame(week,col_a,col_b,col_c)
```

```
  week col_a col_b col_c
1    1     1     4     4
2    1     2     2     2
3    1     2     3     3
4    2     4     1     2
5    2     2     2     2
6    3     7     5     4
```

```
weightsreprex <- data.frame(county = c("col_a", "col_b", "col_c")
                             , weights = c(.3721, .3794, .2485))
```

How do I weight each column and then get the mean? Is there a simpler way than just multiplying each column by its weight in a new column (col_a_weighted) and then taking the rowmean of the weighted columns only?

Tried weighted.means, rowmeans, group_by and summarise

Comment: Are you looking for a rowwise weighted mean based on the weights of each column, or a weighted mean of the entire dataframe, or a weekly mean? Can you post your expected output?

Comment: ...or at least the shape of the expected output. 3x2 (week column and weighted mean column), 6x5 (same as input with one new column with the weighted mean for each row), or something else?

Answer (score 2):

We may use `*` for matrix multiplication:

```
dfreprex$wtmean <- as.matrix(dfreprex[,-1]) %*% as.matrix(weightsreprex[, 2])
dfreprex

  week col_a col_b col_c wtmean
1    1     1     4     4 2.8837
2    1     2     2     2 2.0000
3    1     2     3     3 2.6279
4    2     4     1     2 2.3648
5    2     2     2     2 2.0000
6    3     7     5     4 5.4957
```

We might also use `crossprod`

```
crossprod(t(as.matrix(dfreprex[,-1])),  as.matrix(weightsreprex[, 2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stats::weighted.mean()` here:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dfreprex <- structure(list(week = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), col_a = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 7), col_b = c(4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5), col_c = c(4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

weightsreprex <- data.frame(county = c("col_a", "col_b", "col_c"), weights = c(.3721, .3794, .2485))

dfreprex %>%  
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(wt_avg = weighted.mean(c(col_a, col_b, col_c), weightsreprex$weights))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    week col_a col_b col_c wt_avg
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     4     4   2.88
#> 2     1     2     2     2   2   
#> 3     1     2     3     3   2.63
#> 4     2     4     1     2   2.36
#> 5     2     2     2     2   2   
#> 6     3     7     5     4   5.50
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>